# How do I delete xpcproxy executable from /usr/libexec folder on my Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, firewall

How do I delete `xpcproxy` executable from `/usr/libexec` folder on my Mac? When I dragged it to Trash, it did not delete, nor was <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⇦ Backspace</kbd> helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to do it ?

Comment: The steps vary and the ramifications change based on which version of macOS you have.

Comment: I'd say this smells like an X-Y question. What's your goal in trying to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you want to delete it, so I'll assume you know what you're doing.

`/usr/libexec` is a folder for programs that are used by other programs. `xpcproxy` is owned by root, and so you'll need **at least** root privileges (typically via `sudo`) to delete it.

In addition, you **may** have Apple's [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) if your OS is fairly recent vintage. If you have SIP, you'll need to disable it before you can delete this file. There are numerous guides ([like this one for Catalina](https://howtomacos.com/2019/11/01/disable-system-integrity-protection-in-macos-catalina/)) explaining how to disable SIP, so I won't repeat them here.